# EC2 unable to ping google.com

Tags: amazon-ec2, subnet, amazon-vpc

We created new VPC that  has four subnets, two private and two public.

Private and public will be **Mumbai A** **Mumbai B** region.

When I ping google.com from public Mumbai A it is not working. When I ping google.com from Public Mumbai B, result is the same. I tried with two servers on each.

Note:
All servers have the same security configuration.

How do we resolve this?

Comment: If it's in a public subnet, it needs an elastic IP. If it's in a private one, it needs a NAT gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Check a couple of things:

- Is Internet gateway configured for Public subnets?
- Is NAT gateway configured for Private subnets?
- Are the correct *Route tables* attached to the respective subnets?
- Do the hosts in Public subnets have *Public or Elastic IP*?
- Do *Security Group* and NACL permit outbound traffic?
- If you still can't find the solution consult *VPC Flow Logs*, there may be some clue.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful..

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38690012/aws-vpc-internet-gateway-vs-nat

The private subnets need a path to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

Because i disabled ping but in outbound i have to enable then only it will work.